# "Array Issue occurred while parsing JSON file while getting file_get_contents()"

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, woocommerce

i am getting this error

> Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in /home/stageidg/public_html/cornerstone/wp-content/themes/cornerstone-child/functions.php on line 215
>   An error occurred while parsing Array file.

this is line 215:

```
function parse_json( $file ) {
    $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $file ), true );
    if ( is_array( $json ) && !empty( $json ) ) :
        return $json;   
    else :
        die( 'An error occurred while parsing ' . $file . ' file.' );
    endif;
}
```

Here is the full code. I  am fairly new to API and parsing JSON. So any help would be amazing! if you need to see the API URL I can definitely send you something private. But just to let you know that the API is public and its using Swagger API if that helps anything.

```
//define( 'FILE_TO_IMPORT', 'xxxx' );
//require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
//use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;
//if ( ! file_exists( FILE_TO_IMPORT ) ) :
    //die( 'Unable to find ' . FILE_TO_IMPORT );
//endif;    
//$woocommerce = new Client(
   // 'xxxx',
    //'xxxx', 
    //'xxxx',
    //[
      //  'wp_api' => true,
      //  'version' => 'wc/v2',
       // 'query_string_auth' => true
    //]
//);
try {
    $response = wp_remote_get("PUBLIC API URL" );
    $json = parse_json( $response );
    // Import Attributes
    foreach ( get_attributes_from_json( $json ) as $product_attribute_name => $product_attribute ) :
        $attribute_data = array(
            'name' => $product_attribute_name,
            'slug' => 'pa_' . strtolower( $product_attribute_name ),
            'type' => 'select',
            'order_by' => 'menu_order',
            'has_archives' => true
        );
        $wc_attribute = $woocommerce->post( 'products/attributes', $attribute_data );
        if ( $wc_attribute ) :
            status_message( 'Attribute added. ID: '. $wc_attribute['id'] );
            // store attribute ID so that we can use it later for creating products and variations
            $added_attributes[$product_attribute_name]['id'] = $wc_attribute['id'];

            // Import: Attribute terms
            foreach ( $product_attribute['terms'] as $term ) :
                $attribute_term_data = array(
                    'name' => $term
                );
                $wc_attribute_term = $woocommerce->post( 'products/attributes/'. $wc_attribute['id'] .'/terms', $attribute_term_data );
                if ( $wc_attribute_term ) :
                    status_message( 'Attribute term added. ID: '. $wc_attribute['id'] );
                    // store attribute terms so that we can use it later for creating products
                    $added_attributes[$product_attribute_name]['terms'][] = $term;
                endif;  

            endforeach;
        endif;      
    endforeach;
    $data = get_products_and_variations_from_json( $json, $added_attributes );
    // Merge products and product variations so that we can loop through products, then its variations
    $product_data = merge_products_and_variations( $data['products'], $data['product_variations'] );
    // Import: Products
    foreach ( $product_data as $k => $product ) :
        if ( isset( $product['variations'] ) ) :
            $_product_variations = $product['variations']; // temporary store variations array
            // Unset and make the $product data correct for importing the product.
            unset($product['variations']);
        endif;      
            $wc_product = $woocommerce->post( 'products', $product );
            if ( $wc_product ) :
                status_message( 'Product added. ID: '. $wc_product['id'] );
            endif;
        if ( isset( $_product_variations ) ) :
            // Import: Product variations
            // Loop through our temporary stored product variations array and add them
            foreach ( $_product_variations as $variation ) :
                $wc_variation = $woocommerce->post( 'products/'. $wc_product['id'] .'/variations', $variation );
                if ( $wc_variation ) :
                    status_message( 'Product variation added. ID: '. $wc_variation['id'] . ' for product ID: ' . $wc_product['id'] );
                endif;  
            endforeach; 
            // Don't need it anymore
            unset($_product_variations);
        endif;
    endforeach;

} catch ( HttpClientException $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); // Error message
}
/**
 * Merge products and variations together. 
 * Used to loop through products, then loop through product variations.
 *
 * @param  array $product_data
 * @param  array $product_variations_data
 * @return array
*/
function merge_products_and_variations( $product_data = array(), $product_variations_data = array() ) {
    foreach ( $product_data as $k => $product ) :
        foreach ( $product_variations_data as $k2 => $product_variation ) :
            if ( $product_variation['_parent_product_id'] == $product['_product_id'] ) :
                // Unset merge key. Don't need it anymore
                unset($product_variation['_parent_product_id']);
                $product_data[$k]['variations'][] = $product_variation;
            endif;
        endforeach;
        // Unset merge key. Don't need it anymore
        unset($product_data[$k]['_product_id']);
    endforeach;
    return $product_data;
}
/**
 * Get products from JSON and make them ready to import according WooCommerce API properties. 
 *
 * @param  array $json
 * @param  array $added_attributes
 * @return array
*/
function get_products_and_variations_from_json( $json, $added_attributes ) {
    $product = array();
    $product_variations = array();
    foreach ( $json as $key => $pre_product ) :
        if ( $pre_product['type'] == 'simple' ) :
            $product[$key]['_product_id'] = (string) $pre_product['product_id'];
            $product[$key]['name'] = (string) $pre_product['name'];
            $product[$key]['description'] = (string) $pre_product['description'];
            $product[$key]['regular_price'] = (string) $pre_product['regular_price'];
            // Stock
            $product[$key]['manage_stock'] = (bool) $pre_product['manage_stock'];
            if ( $pre_product['stock'] > 0 ) :
                $product[$key]['in_stock'] = (bool) true;
                $product[$key]['stock_quantity'] = (int) $pre_product['stock'];
            else :
                $product[$key]['in_stock'] = (bool) false;
                $product[$key]['stock_quantity'] = (int) 0;
            endif;  
        elseif ( $pre_product['type'] == 'variable' ) :
            $product[$key]['_product_id'] = (string) $pre_product['product_id'];
            $product[$key]['type'] = 'variable';
            $product[$key]['name'] = (string) $pre_product['name'];
            $product[$key]['description'] = (string) $pre_product['description'];
            $product[$key]['regular_price'] = (string) $pre_product['regular_price'];
            // Stock
            $product[$key]['manage_stock'] = (bool) $pre_product['manage_stock'];
            if ( $pre_product['stock'] > 0 ) :
                $product[$key]['in_stock'] = (bool) true;
                $product[$key]['stock_quantity'] = (int) $pre_product['stock'];
            else :
                $product[$key]['in_stock'] = (bool) false;
                $product[$key]['stock_quantity'] = (int) 0;
            endif;  
            $attribute_name = $pre_product['attribute_name'];
            $product[$key]['attributes'][] = array(
                    'id' => (int) $added_attributes[$attribute_name]['id'],
                    'name' => (string) $attribute_name,
                    'position' => (int) 0,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'variation' => true,
                    'options' => $added_attributes[$attribute_name]['terms']
            );
        elseif ( $pre_product['type'] == 'product_variation' ) :    
            $product_variations[$key]['_parent_product_id'] = (string) $pre_product['parent_product_id'];
            $product_variations[$key]['description'] = (string) $pre_product['description'];
            $product_variations[$key]['regular_price'] = (string) $pre_product['regular_price'];
            // Stock
            $product_variations[$key]['manage_stock'] = (bool) $pre_product['manage_stock'];
            if ( $pre_product['stock'] > 0 ) :
                $product_variations[$key]['in_stock'] = (bool) true;
                $product_variations[$key]['stock_quantity'] = (int) $pre_product['stock'];
            else :
                $product_variations[$key]['in_stock'] = (bool) false;
                $product_variations[$key]['stock_quantity'] = (int) 0;
            endif;
            $attribute_name = $pre_product['attribute_name'];
            $attribute_value = $pre_product['attribute_value'];
            $product_variations[$key]['attributes'][] = array(
                'id' => (int) $added_attributes[$attribute_name]['id'],
                'name' => (string) $attribute_name,
                'option' => (string) $attribute_value
            );
        endif;      
    endforeach;     
    $data['products'] = $product;
    $data['product_variations'] = $product_variations;
    return $data;
}   
/**
 * Get attributes and terms from JSON.
 * Used to import product attributes.
 *
 * @param  array $json
 * @return array
*/
function get_attributes_from_json( $json ) {
    $product_attributes = array();
    foreach( $json as $key => $pre_product ) :
        if ( !empty( $pre_product['attribute_name'] ) && !empty( $pre_product['attribute_value'] ) ) :
            $product_attributes[$pre_product['attribute_name']]['terms'][] = $pre_product['attribute_value'];
        endif;
    endforeach;     
    return $product_attributes;
}
/**
 * Parse JSON file.
 *
 * @param  string $file
 * @return array
*/
function parse_json( $file ) {
    $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $file ), true );
    if ( is_array( $json ) && !empty( $json ) ) :
        return $json;   
    else :
        die( 'An error occurred while parsing ' . $file . ' file.' );
    endif;
}
/**
 * Print status message.
 *
 * @param  string $message
 * @return string
*/
function status_message( $message ) {
    echo $message . "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you not get? The error messages says it all: what you're passing is not a string.

Comment: that's because `wp_remote_get` returns an array

Comment: You're using the results from `wp_remote_get()` incorrectly. That function returns an array. See the Wordpress [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) for more.

Comment: I figured it out after a few tries and i did realize i wasn't getting the body. but now i got it! now the fun part is passing it into woocommerce!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `$json = parse_json($response['body']);` instead of 
`$json = parse_json($response);`.

Comment: thank you for that..i realized i wasn't getting the body after smacking my head on the wall a few times lol! i appreciate the help!